# Worksheet_Change - 3 column multiplication evaluate to

Tags: vba

I'm new to vba  and frustrated.

I have the following code :

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim VolRange As Range
    Dim AffectVolRange As Range
    Set VolRange = ActiveSheet.Range("AH:AK")
    Set AffectVolRange = Intersect(Target, VolRange)
      
    If Not AffectVolRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim vRow As Variant
        For Each vRow In AffectVolRange.Rows
            With VolRange
               Cells(vRow.Row, 37).Value = .Cells(vRow.Row, 34).Value * .Cells(vRow.Row, 35).Value * 
             .Cells(vRow.Row, 36).Value
            
             End With
        Next vRow
    End If
End Sub
```

Initial value  in columns 34,35,36, is null

Comment: You need to explain what are you doing, what result do you obtain and what result do you expect.

Comment: User populates value in column 34,35,36 and I except in column 37  to be  the  result  of 34*35*36 . in the same Sub  I have another calculation that works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almos got it.
Take into account that your column indexes are relative to your new range, so 1, 2, 3, 4.
Also you need to disable the events with `Application.EnableEvents = False` to avoid recursive call to the function on the cells changed by the code event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim VolRange As Range
    Dim AffectVolRange As Range
    Set VolRange = ActiveSheet.Range("AH:AK")
    Set AffectVolRange = Intersect(Target, VolRange)
      
    If Not AffectVolRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim vRow As Variant
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each vRow In AffectVolRange.Rows
            With VolRange
                .Cells(vRow.Row, 4).Value = .Cells(vRow.Row, 1).Value _
                * .Cells(vRow.Row, 2).Value _
                * .Cells(vRow.Row, 3).Value
            
             End With
        Next vRow
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]